# Remove errors from sublists after Excel import

Tags: list-manipulation, import, excel

I have a very long list such as:

https://pastebin.com/9vYDLsVp

At the end of each sublist for some reason I have `{,-6}`. How can I remove that from each sublist of the list?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The list is generated getting data from an Excel file and for some reason at the end it gives me `{,-6}` using:

```
Extract[Import["file.xlsx"], 1][[3 ;; All, {i, i + 1}]]
```

Comment: `Most/@list` or `list[[All, ;;-2]]`?

Comment: `Most/@First[Import["file.xlsx"]]` or `Import["file.xlsx"][[1,All,;;-2]]]`

Comment: Thank you! It works !

Comment: @kglr here's another list: https://pastebin.com/rSVRyTge . It doesn't seem to work on that one. How can I remove all the `{,-6}` values from that one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have a problem that Excel puts some errors containing string expressions. If they appear in random places but you know how they look you can delete them based on their pattern. After you import:

```
data=ToExpression[Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/rSVRyTge"]];
```

you can remove them whether by exact pattern

```
DeleteCases[data,{"",-6 ""},Infinity]
```

or some generalization

```
DeleteCases[data,{___,_String,___},Infinity]
```